# mysql query from hourly to 2 hourly

Tags: mysql

How can I change the query below to get 2 hours instead of 1

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(x.time,'%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00')
     , avg(Ph) avg_Ph
  FROM Ph x where time >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
 GROUP 
    BY DATE_FORMAT(x.time,'%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(x.time)/7200)*7200),'%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') AS `two_hour`
     , avg(Ph) avg_Ph
  FROM Ph x where time >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
 GROUP 
    BY `two_hour`
```